# Authorization Required 500 internal server error apache http server java sardine implementation

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, webdav, httpserver

I am trying to upload file in apache http server(Some Url) using WEBDAV sardine       concept..I coded for file uploading and Apache server configuration and all.
    I wanna do this file Read and Write With authentication.. So,i added .htaccess password file in apache.. When i am trying to upload file with authentication,
    file Upload is not happening,But it is prompting authentication for file read operation. and am getting some authorization required error -500 Internal Server Error.
    I dont know why i am getting this error.. i think it is not reading my password file,while uploading alone.. I dont know how to clear this error..
    and when i do the same file upload operation without authentication,then file upload is working,But,it is not prompting authentication for file Read..

```
I configured my apache http server 2.2 using below Link

http://www.mkyong.com/apache/how-to-enable-webdav-in-apache-server-2-2-x-windows/

This is my httpd-dav.conf file

Alias /sites "E:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites"
<Directory "E:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites">

DavLockDB "E:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/var/DavLock"
#DAVMinTimeout 600

Alias /sites "E:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites"
<Directory "E:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/sites">

Dav On

AllowOverride None
Options None

Order Allow,Deny
Order deny,allow
Deny from 10.80.100.160
Allow from 10.80.100.160

AuthType Digest
AuthName DAV-upload

# Options Indexes
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks

AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files/user.passwd"
#AccessFileName "C:/Program Files/user.passwd"
AuthDigestProvider file
AllowOverride None

# Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
# to the admin user.
<Limit GET POST PROPFIND OPTIONS HEAD>
# require user admin
require valid-user
</Limit>
</Directory>

This is my htaccess password file

admin:DAV-upload:encrypted pwd
Nagu:DAV-upload:encrypted pwd
Prashant:DAV-upload:encrypted pwd

I enabled Following LoadModule and Include Statement in my httpd.conf by referring below link

http://www.mkyong.com/apache/how-to-enable-webdav-in-apache-server-2-2-x-windows/

LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

Please help me dude.. Thanks in advance..
```